# Bluetooth gone awol on Ubu 16.05 and 18.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

A sad story: home from holiday in Spain, I want to send some photos from my mobile to this laptop. Worked before the holiday. Bluetooth won't switch on on the laptop.

I followed these instructions, which worked for me previously:

> 1. Start the bluetooth daemon
>
> Go to your terminal and type : sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
>
> 2. Reinstall packages
>
> If this doesn't work, go to your terminal and type : sudo apt-get
>   purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth 
>   sudo apt-get install blueman
>   bluez-utils bluez bluetooth Then run : sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth
>   start

Purging bluetooth had a strange effect: System Settings was lost! The Ubu 16.05 install was broken, though still running.

I decided to upgrade to 18.04 from the software manager. Took a while, but it got there.

Seems now, the reason bluetooth will not start is because there is no bluetooth adaptor (see screenshot). Maybe it broke while I was on holiday, but the the laptop was unplugged and off. When I came back from holiday, I first updated everything.[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to get the bluetooth adaptor going again?